# Difference between codes of lexical scope

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

I want to know the difference between the following two block of codes:

```js
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    return function a(){
        console.log(a) 
    }
}
foo()(); // output: function a(){...}
```

vs

```js
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    function a(){};
    return () => {console.log(a)} 
}
foo()(); // output: private variable
```

In the first block of code, based on the hoisting, the function a definition should be hoisted, and then `var a = 'private variable'` rewrite the `a`, but why the `console.log(a)` output the function definition?

Comment: I think this will help you http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: There is some concept of activation object which sets the property of a variable in a scope be it in global,function or eval scope..each have it's own rules for the final value of property.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case when you are referencing `a` in `console.log` you are actually referencing the function `a` and it already shadowed over the `var = a` so you don't have access to it.

On the second option, `function a() {}` actually moves above the `var a = 'private variable'` so the code would look like this:

```js
function a() {};
var a;
a = 'private variable';
```

That is why when you call `foo()()` your `var a = 'private variable';` is shadowing over the function `a` and you see `private variable` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about hoisting. The first variant does not actually declare a function, it is merely a function *expression* (i.e., a 'lambda' or a 'closure') which doesn't declare anything within it's own lexical scope. What the 'a' does in that expression is assign the 'name' property of the resulting function object, and make it available to it's body's lexical scope:

e.g. in node:

```
> const f = function a() {console.log(a);}
undefined
> a
Thrown:
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> f
[Function: a]
> f()
[Function: a]
undefined
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code could help you understand what is happening.

When you use `return function a() { ... }` it will not considered as `function declaration` but will be treated as `Variable assignment` like `a = function () { ... }; return a;`. And `return` will execute later `a` will hold value as `function`.

As below code you can be sure that assignment want take place until it reaches that line. So when we use `foo(1)();` it outputs `private variable`.

```js
function foo(returnString) {
  var a = 'private variable';
  if (returnString)
    return function() { console.log(a); };
  return function a() { console.log(a); };
}
foo()(); // output: function a() { console.log(a); }
foo(1)(); // output: private variable
```

---

In your second case it is quite simple. As per [Order of precedence](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-order-of-precedence)

1. Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration
2. Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations

```js
function foo() {
  var a = 'private variable';
  function a() {};
  return () => { console.log(a); }
}
foo()(); // output: private variable
```